# Using regex to get substring for multiple possible strings

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm not very good at regex with powershell and could use some help. The reason I'm using regex here is to accomidate for whitespaces (and any other text I can't think of atm that is not expected), so then the junk is stripped away to get the value that is wanted.

I'm trying the  following code...

```
[String[]]$listOfStrings = @(' token = true ', ' token = false ', ' token = True ', ' token = False ')

For ($stringNumber = 0; $stringNumber -lt $listOfStrings.length; $stringNumber++)
{
    [String]$stringTest = ($listOfStrings[$stringNumber] -replace '*token*=','').Trim()
    Write-Host $stringTest
}
```

The output should be the following...

```
true
false
True
False
```

However, I'm getting the following error message...

```
Invalid regular expression pattern: *token*=.
At :line:5 char:63
+       [String]$stringTest = ($listOfStrings[$stringNumber] -replace <<<<  '*token*=','').Trim()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
[String]$stringTest = ($listOfStrings[$stringNumber] -replace '.*token.*=','').Trim()
```

Notice the `.*`.

You may also want to reference https://regex101.com/ in the future when you are writing your regular expressions.  Many find that site quite useful.

Comment: Unfortunately my work blocks that website, but I'll check it out and save as favs when I get home. Thanks a lot :)